# Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred

Tags: android

In my app I am getting such error in the logcat . 
I am not sure of the reason.

Please help .

```
    11-10 18:55:38.468 828-892/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '6762ba7 notifapp.delusions.com.notificationapp/notifapp.delusions.com.notificationapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
    11-10 18:55:38.468 828-892/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6762ba7 notifapp.delusions.com.notificationapp/notifapp.delusions.com.notificationapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    11-10 18:55:38.469 278-920/? D/GraphicBuffer: free, handle(0x7f7c050340) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
    11-10 18:55:38.469 828-3708/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '6762ba7 notifapp.delusions.com.notificationapp/notifapp.delusions.com.notificationapp.MainActivity (server)'
    11-10 18:55:38.469 278-902/? I/SurfaceFlinger: EventThread Client Pid (17671) disconnected by (278)
    11-10 18:55:38.469 278-902/? I/SurfaceFlinger: EventThread Client Pid (17671)      disconnected by (278)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  Please post your answer if so.

Comment: if you found answer please post.